# How to animate a line on hover link

Tags: javascript, css

How can I make the underline animation like that in https://www.javascript.com/ when hovering on the navigation anchors?

I don't know how to do it so I have no code yet!

I know how to write `@keyframes` from CSS3 but I don't know how to create such animation.

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul id="navbar">
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>



#navbar li:hover a {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: can anybody explain why the hell this question is downvoted?

Comment: Because this site does not exist to hand feed you tutorials. Search, try something, then explain which specific part of your code is not working the way you expect

Comment: @takendarkk I searched a lot. I even tried viewing source of that page and made few tries but you clearly didn't understand what I meant with "I don't know how to do it"

Comment: I don't know how to do it and I have no code is the same as show me how to do it which is the same as a tutorial. If you really did make a few tries then post that code here and explain which specific part is not working the way you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used `:pseudo` element for `border` effect and on `hover` its changing `width` from `0%` to `100%`

```css
#navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}
#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  padding:10px 0;
  position: relative;
}
#navbar li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  transition: .5s linear;
}
#navbar li a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

another method is you can use a `linear-gradient` with `background-position`

```css
#navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}
#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}
#navbar li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, red 50%, white 50%, white);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, red 50%, white 50%, white);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, red 50%, white 50%, white);
  background-image: linear-gradient(left, red 50%, white 50%, white);
  background-size: 200%;
  background-position-x: 100%;
  transition: .5s linear;
}
#navbar li a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
  background-position-x: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Or another method with `overflow:hidden` and `left`

```css
#navbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
}
#navbar li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#navbar li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  transition: .5s linear;
}
#navbar li a:hover:after {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul id="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I've never used that pseudo class. anyway, shouldn't it be `::` instead of `:`?

Comment: `::` css3 selector `:` is css2 selector for difference use `::` and `:` in ie8 and see @rz3r0

Comment: thank you for your clear answer!

Comment: your welcome was happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can find those effects and more in [this tutorial on the awesome Codrops website](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/05/13/inspiration-for-text-styles-and-hover-effects/).

[A demo here.](http://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeLinkEffects/#cl-effect-11)

All of them, as mentioned, rely on pusedo elements.

> If you have a look at the Kukuri effect, you will see that, on hover, a bar appears by sliding in from the left. This bar will “drag” along the colored version of the text which we pack into the ::before pseudo element. We set the initial position of the bar to be outside of the link box which we set to overflow: hidden.

It should be simple to implement them from scratch once you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [CSS Transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

On JavaScript.com to get that effect they're using border-bottom rather than text-decoration.

So consider the following:

```
a{
    border-bottom:2px solid transparent;
    transition:border 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
    border-bottom:2px solid #fff;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `:after` to make the underlines:

```css
a {
  color:#00f;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:inline-block;
}
a:after {
  width: 0;
  display:block;
  background:#00f;
  height:3px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  content:"";
}
a:hover {
  color:#00f;
}
a:hover:after {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Click here</a>
```